# C# Display in XML Format

Tags: c#, xml

I am expecting an xml as output when execute the following

```
XElement Root = XElement.Load(@"d:\xmlfiles\Customers.xml");
XElement BringContact = Root.Element("Contact");
Response.Write(BringContact);
```

as

```
<Contact>
  <Company>Alfreds Futterkiste</Company>
  <City>Berlin</City>
</Contact>
```

But the Response.Write() displays  values only
as

```
Alfreds Futterkiste Berlin
```

What is the code change do i need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because the browser is interpreting it as markup. Use "view source" in your browser to see the actual output.

You can also explicitly tell the browser you are returning xml by setting the content type:

```
  Response.ContentType = "text/xml";
  Response.ContentEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `HttpUtility.HtmlEncode()` to get the < > brackets to appear in the browser.